# Disposing an XDocument object

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

How do I "dispose" an XDocument object? I am using it to parse an XML string and then save the file to the file system. In the same method I then need to access this file and run a command line tool on it.

The code is as follows:

```
string filepath = "...";
string filename = "...";
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
xdoc.Save(filepath + filename);

Process p = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("rst.exe", args)); // the args use the file saved above
```

I put a breakpoint on the line where I call the command line tool, and then tried to open the file manually myself, but it wouldn't load until I stopped the debugger.

**edit:** Thanks for the answers. I've narrowed down the problem.. after the file is saved, and with the breakpoint on "Process p = ...", I *am* able to open the file, but I can't access it using `http://qualifiedapppath/path/file.xml`, and the command line tool I am using will only accept a URL as a parameter. After stopping the debugger, I am able to access the file through http. What process is preventing access to it while the method is running?

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: not getting any errors, the command line tool just fails to execute because (i assume) it can't access the file

Comment: just curious, are you able to open the file (after it has been created) manually in notepad and able to edit it?

Comment: btw, `Path.Combine` is a preferred way of combining a path and filename; but: there's nothing you need to do here - no dispose etc is required

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I've made an edit above.

Comment: If the file is on the same computer, try using `file:///C:/....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't - it doesn't even implement IDisposable. The XDocument and XElement classes use XmlReader under the covers and handle the disposing of the underlying reader for you. Simply right-click on XDocument class and select *Go To Definition*, you may not find IDisposable implemented by this class.

To reclaim the memory, set XDocument object reference to null and GC will recollect the acquired memory.

**ADDED:**

For the second part of your question, use this Uri if file is available locally this way:

```
var uri = new Uri("file:///C:/path/file.xml");
```

You can also verify the file location using this piece of code:

```
if (uri.IsFile)
{
    var filePath = uri.LocalPath; // C:/path/file.xml
}
```

You can use HTTP if you configure the virtual directory in IIS to locate that file.

Comment: You don't need to set XDocument object reference to null for the collection by GC. It's not required.

Comment: Thanks sooo much!  I'm using an XElement in a WixSharp installer and it was keeping open the application settings file that I update and not letting the installer launch the application after install (file in use by another process error).  Setting the variable for the XElement to null (after my update) did the trick.  File released.  App started.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 7):

XDocument is a class that stores an in-memory copy of an XML document.  Classes implement IDisposable because they use unmanaged resources **other** than memory.  Memory is already capably managed by the garbage collector.

Since XDocument only consumes memory, it doesn't have a need for a Dispose method.

Answer (score 1):

It doesnt implement IDisposable so if you just want to free the memory of it, set all references to null and the garbage collector will remove it when it needs to.