# OutOfMemoryException in Windows Phone app

Tags: c#, windows-phone

i make gallery in my app

when i back and choose another album system.OutOfMemoryException occurs

this is my Xaml

```
   <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ScrollViewer Margin="0,1,0,71" >
            <Grid Width="475"  Name="picbtn" Background="WhiteSmoke" >

            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

this is my code

```
     string type;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 4050;
    int i = 0;
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        if (e.NavigationMode != NavigationMode.Back)
        {
            type = NavigationContext.QueryString["name"];

            ReadFromXml(type);
        }
    }
    private void ReadFromXml(string type)
    {

        XDocument xml;
        if (type == "day")
        {
            xml = XDocument.Load("DayimagesData.xml");
        }
        else
        {
            xml = XDocument.Load("NightmagesData.xml");
        }

        var query = from c in xml.Root.Descendants("posts")

                    select c.Element("image").Value;
        foreach (var name in query)
        {


            CreateGrid(name);
            i++;
            if (i % 3 == 0)
            {
                x += 150;
                y -= 150;
            }
        }

    }
    private void CreateGrid(string data)
    {

        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(
                new Uri(@"images\" + data, UriKind.Relative)
                );
        Grid g1 = new Grid
        {
            Width = 150,
            Height = 150,
            Margin = new Thickness(0, x, 0, y),
            DataContext = data

        };
        Image im = new Image
        {

            Source = image
        };
        g1.Children.Add(im);
        if (i % 3 == 0)
        { g1.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left; }
        else if (i % 3 == 1)
        {
            g1.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        }
        else
        {
            g1.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        }

        picbtn.Children.Add(g1);
        g1.Tap += Grid_Tap;
    }
```

is there are any method to clear the memory when the back clicked ??
i try 
GC.collect
but the same issue happened

Comment: It is not possible to answer your question without see your work/code etc..

Comment: i will add my code now

Comment: on back, dispose your gallery...

Comment: how can i do this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dispose XDocument and BitmapImage properly .From your code those are the memory consumers on high note.

Comment: for disposing the Xdocument refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874869/disposing-an-xdocument-object<br>
for disposing BitmapImage refer http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dee7cb68-aca3-402b-b159-2de933f933f1/disposing-a-wpf-image-or-bitmapimage-so-the-source-picture-file-can-be-modified?forum=wpf.

Comment: From the available code I assume you're creating a new grid every time,Are you destroying it when no longer needed?. Consider declaring and using the same grid for the entire process.You can clear the grid when reloading the images again.

Comment: private void Back_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            picbtn.Children.Clear();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
            NavigationService.GoBack();
            MainPage.OnRequestInterstitialClick(sender, e);
            
        }

Comment: If you're clearing grid's then i can't guess why it is happening,Btw GC.Collect() and other forced GC operations will hurt the performance.
The framework knows when to do it.

Comment: :( i don't know the problem